# Mongoose not resolving callback queries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been working on this project for 2 years now, and I'm thinking this was caused by the recent update, but am wondering if there are any kind, intelligent, **Mongoose/NoSQL DBA**, souls out there who would do the awesome service of helping me either track-down, and/or resolve this issue.

So, as you can see below, this is a **simple mongoose find query** over express to MongoDB. This is rather evident, at a high-level, and for most devs, the interactions will be natural, as any Mongo, Express, Node Stack using Mongoose.

The is issue is that, when I send this query, disregarding environment (a production project), it does not resolve.

**The "data" seems to get lost somewhere, and therefore, the query simply never resolves.**

It's a simple setup, really a test endpoint, so help out, run it through, and send some feedback.

Greatly Appreciated!

### Model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const TestSchema = new Schema({
  data: {
    type: String,
    unique: false,
    required: true
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

TestSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

### Constructor.js

```
class Constructor {
constructor() {}
    getAll() {
        return TestSchema.find({}, function (err, tests) {})
    }
}
module.exports = Constructor
```

### db.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Connect to db
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, err => {
    if (err) 
        return console.log("Cannot connect to DB")
    connectionCallback()
    console.log("DB Connected")
});

let connectionCallback = () => {}

module.exports.onConnect = cb => {
    connectionCallback = cb
}
```

### App.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const ip = require('ip');
let db = require('./db')
const router = express.Router();
const port = 8888;
const http = require('http').createServer(app);


let ipAddress = 'localhost'; // only works to the local host
try {
  // will enable the server to be accessed from the network
  ipAddress = ip.address();
} catch( err ){
  console.err( err );
}

http.listen(port, ipAddress, 
   () => {
  let message = [
    `Server is running at ${ipAddress}:${port}`,
  ];

  console.log( ...message )
});


db.onConnect(() => {
    let Constructor = require("./pathTo/Constructor")

    let construct = new Constructor()

    app.use('/api', router.get('/test', function(req, res) {construct.getAll()}))
})
```

Comment: Use the driver directly and verify your connectivity works and your database works.

Comment: As an aside, there is no such thing as a mongoose dba because mongoose is not a database.

Comment: Your problem is `return TestSchema.find({}, function (err, tests) {})`. You have to choose between passing values to a callback (then the function wont return anything) OR returning a promise (OR you could make the whole thing synchronous but that is really not an option). The only attractive solution here (so that getAll() does what you intend) is to remove the callback so that `find()` returns a promise. Then you can use `const tests = await getAll();`, and it'll behave *as if* it was synchronous.

Comment: `return TestSchema.find({}).exec();`

Comment: There are NoSQL DBAs...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the `constructor.js` `getAll` function, as you are returning also and passed a callback also, the promise will never be resolved. You should either resolve the promise or return the response from the callback.

Resolve Promise:

```
class Constructor {
constructor() {}
    async getAll() {
        return await TestSchema.find({})
    }
}
module.exports = Constructor
```

Return from callback:

```
    class Constructor {
        constructor() {}
            getAll() {
                TestSchema.find({}, function (err, tests){
                      return tests.   
})
            }
        }
        module.exports = Constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just scaling the project for production. I put the `connectionCallback` in a class and called it with the `createConnection` mongoose function.

Looks like this:

```js
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/db'
const connection = mongoose.createConnection(url, options);
//load models
require('/models').connectionCallback();

modules.export = connectionInstance;
```

Please note, I am no longer using express!